# Calculate complexity of an algorithm. Python

Tags: python, complexity-theory

```
def multi_merge_v1(lst_of_lsts): 
     all = [e for lst in lst_of_lsts for e in lst] 
     merged = [] 
     while all != []: 
         minimum = min(all) 
         merged += [minimum] 
         all.remove(minimum) 
     return merged
```

Please help me calculate the time complexity of this function. I'm totally new to this.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This is not very usefull question, because it lacks any generality. Could you describe maybe the problem here so it will be more "googlable"?

Comment: This question doesn't lack generality. You can generalize the answer fairly easily. This question lacks effort.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have `N` members in your `all` data structure, you're getting `min` each time, of `O(N)` and then removing it, again `O(N)`, you do it `N` times, so you'll end up with an `O(N^2)` time complexity.

you could instead have this:

```
def multi_merge_v1(lst_of_lsts): 
     all = [e for lst in lst_of_lsts for e in lst]
     return(sorted(all))
```

which has `O(N log(N))` time complexity.

Comment: No it doesn't. It only returns `None` if your `all` is `None`. Look [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Comment: @BlackMamba `list.sort` returns None and modifies the list in-place. The global function `sorted` on the other hand doesn't modify its argument (except to the extent that iterating over it modifies it) and returns a new list with the sorted data.